# google script for conditional formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible by script or formula in google sheets to change the colour of 6 cells in a row that are joining to change to black background white text if all 6 contain the word IN.

I have a schedule and would like to identify easily if one person is offered 6 days consecutive work

Thanks Danny

Comment: because I think the only way it can be doing is by using google script - if it in the wrong place i'm sorry I'm new to this

Comment: [Here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting) is a guide that can help you out. Click the link and you will be redirected to the google sheet official documentation. For apps script Advanced Sheets Service check[ this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets).